Non-vanishing of product of zero divisors in quotients modulo $n$
This might be of practical importance and even partial answer will help.
Let $n$ be odd squarefree integer with known factorization $n=\prod p_i$
with $N$ prime factors.
Later we are not asking about all $n$, but for existence of $n$
with $N$ prime factors and known $p_i$.
Let $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $K=R[w]/(w^2-1)$.
$K$ is similar to the gaussian integers modulo $n$, but instead
of complex multiplication the multiplication is related to
difference of squares.
It is easy to show that $$(a+wb)(a-wb)=a^2-b^2 \qquad (1)$$
If $a,b \in R$ satisfy $a^2-b^2=0$ then $a+wb$ is zero divisor by (1)
and observe that it is possible $ a \ne \pm b$ because of non-trivial
square roots of $1$.
Define $W(i)$ to be the smallest positive
integer satisfying $W(i) \equiv -1 \pmod{p_i}, W(i) \equiv 1 \pmod{\frac{n}{p_i}}$. $W(i)$ is efficiently computable via the Chinese remainder theorem.
We have $W(i)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ and $1+w W(i)$ is zero divisor.
Let $N_2=\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$.
Define the set $S^+=\{1+w\cdot W(i) : 1 \le i \le N_2\}$ and $S^-=\{1-w\cdot W(i) : 1 \le i \le N_2\}$
For all $i$ we have $S^+[i]\cdot S^-[i]=0$
Let $S=S^+ \cup S^-$.

Q1 Is it true that $\forall T \subset S, \prod T =0$ iff $T$ contains
at least one pair $(S^+[i],S^-[i])$?

The if part was shown above.

Q2 In case answer is hard, is there efficient algorithm to check
candidate $S$?


Q3 In case of negative answer, is it possible to get positive result
for $K_2=R[w]/(w^2+1)$ and zero divisor $W_2(i)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$?


It seems like it's useful to use $K = R[w]/(w-1) \times R[w]/(w+1)$, as $R[w] / (w - a)$ are quite simple

Indeed, @DanielWeber's comment shows that $K$ is isomorphic to $R \times R$, with $r\in R$ going to $(r,r)$ and $w$ going to $(1,-1)$. The idempotents are $(1,0)=(w+1)2^{-1}$ and $(0,1)=(w-1)2^{-1}$. This makes the zero divisors obvious, and should answer all your questions.

@DaveBenson Many thanks. Would you please give more hints about R[w]/(w^2+1) question?

@joro For that, you need to divide your primes into two sets, according to whether they are one or three modulo four, and decompose $R$ correspondingly, say $R=R_1\times R_2$. Then $R[w]/(w^2+1)$ is a product of $R_1[w]/(w^2+1)$ and $R_2[w]/(w^2+1)$. The first is $R_1\times R_1$ by the same method as before, while the second is a product of fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. This again makes it clear what the zero divisors are.

If $N_2 \ge 4$ there is a counterexample to Q1:
$$(1 + wW_1)(1 + wW_2)(1 - wW_3)(1 - wW_4) =
{W_1 W_2 W_3 W_4 + W_1 W_2 - W_1 W_3 - W_2 W_3 - W_1 W_4 - W_2 W_4 + W_3 W_4 + 1} + {w( -W_1 W_2 W_3 - W_1 W_2 W_4 + W_1 W_3 W_4 + W_2 W_3 W_4 + W_1 + W_2 - W_3 - W_4)}$$ is easily seen to be zero modulo any $p_j$ for $j > 4$ and can be checked to be zero modulo $p_j$ for $1 \le j \le 4$.

@PeterTaylor Thanks, nice counterexample.
